# Discrepencies in Python hard coding string vs str() methods

Tags: string, python-3.x, floating-point

Okay. Here is my minimal working example. When I type this into python 3.6.2:

```
foo = '0.670'
str(foo)
```

I get

```
>>>'0.670'
```

but when I type

```
foo = 0.670
str(foo)
```

I get

```
>>>'0.67'
```

What gives? It is stripping off the zero, which I believe has to do with representing a float on a computer in general. But by using the `str()` method, why can it retain the extra `0` in the first case?

Comment: What happens if you do: `foo = 'noodles 0.670 fussili'` and `str(foo)`? That fact that a string looks like a number doesn't make it one. It remains a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing strings and floats. The string is sequence of code points (one code point represents one character) representing some text and interpreter processing it as a text. The string is always inside single-quotes or double-quotes (e.g. `'Hello'`). The float is a number and Python know it so it also know that `1.0000` is the same as `1.0`.

In the first case you saved into `foo` a string. The `str()` call on string just take the string and return it as is.

In the second case you saved `0.670` as a float (because it's not wrapped in quotes). When Python converting float into a string it always tries create the shortest string possible.

> Why Python automatically truncates the trailing zero?

When you try save some real number into computer's memory you have to convert it into binary representation. Usually (but there some exceptions) it's saved in format described in the standard IEEE 754 and Python uses it for floats too.

Let's go to the some example:

```
from struct import pack
x = -1.53
y = -1.53000
print("X:", pack(">d", x).hex())
print("Y:", pack(">d", y).hex())
```

The `pack()` function takes input and based on given format (`>d`) convert it into bytes. In this case it takes float number and give as how it is saved in memory. If you run the code you will see the `x` and `y` are saved in the memory in the same way. The memory doesn't contain information about the format of saved number.

Of course you can add some information about it but:

1. It would take another memory and it's good practice to use as much memory as you actually need and don't waste it.
2. What would be result of `0.10 + 0.1` should it be `0.2` or `0.20`?

> For scientific purposes and significant figures shouldn't it leave the value as the user defined it?

It doesn't matter how you defined the input number. The important is what format you want to use for presenting. As I said the `str()` always tries create the shortest string possible. `str()` is good for some simple scripts or tests. For scientific purposes (or for uses where some representation is required) you can convert your numbers to string as you want or need.

For example:

```
x = -1655484.4584631
y = 42.0
# always print number with sign and exactly 5 numbers from fractional part
print("{:+.5f}".format(x)) # -1655484.45846
print("{:+.5f}".format(y)) # +42.00000
# always print number in scientific format (sign is showed only when the number is negative)
print("{:-2e}".format(x)) # -1.66e+06
print("{:-2e}".format(y)) # 4.20e+01
```

For more information about formatting numbers and others types look at the [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: In fact (in Python 3) the string is a sequence of [_code points_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). It uses [unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) literals in the source code.

Comment: @Qeek I guess I'm confused why Python automatically truncates the trailing zero. For scientific purposes and significant figures shouldn't it leave the value as the user defined it?

Comment: @Gleland I've extended the answer about your questions.